# Overload operator for set of sets

Tags: c++, overloading

I just build a mini program to understand how this will work because i need this for something a bit more difficult but i can't make this work.

I think i need to define operator overload but i dont know how because they are two objects of `set<set<a>>`

If you compile you will see a big error where it notice that he can't compare `myset == myset2` and i think it will say same for operator `!=` and `=`

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class a{
private:
     int a_;
public:
    int get_a() const{ return a_; }
     void set_a(int aux){ a_=aux;}
     bool operator < (const a& t) const{
         return this->get_a() < t.get_a();
     }
};


class b{
private:
     set<set<a> > b_;
public:
     void set_(set<a> aux){ b_.insert(aux); }
     //Overload operators?
};


int main(){
    b myset;    
    b myset2;

    set<a> subset1;
    set<a> subset2;

    a myint;

    myint.set_a(1);
    subset1.insert(myint);

    myint.set_a(2);
    subset1.insert(myint);

    myint.set_a(3);
    subset1.insert(myint);

    myint.set_a(5);
    subset2.insert(myint);

    myint.set_a(6);
    subset2.insert(myint);

    myint.set_a(7);
    subset2.insert(myint);

    myset.set_(subset1);
    myset.set_(subset2);

    myset2.set_(subset1);
    myset2.set_(subset2);


    if(myset == myset2){
        cout << "They are equal" << endl;
    }

    if(myset != myset2){
        cout << "They are different" << endl;
    }

    b myset3;

    myset3 = myset2; //Copy one into other

}
```

Comment: You are mostly correct. You cannot compare (`==`, `!=`, `<`, etc...) objects unless you implement the appropriate operators. You can still assign (`=`) because a default assignment operator will be generated. This default `=` may not do what you want in all cases. Read [What is the Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for an example of what all to often goes wrong with the default `=` and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your code to work you need to specify following operators (note: they are not created by default)

```
class a{
private: 
     int a_;
public: 
    int get_a() const{ return a_; }
    void set_a(int aux){ a_=aux;}

    /* needed for set insertion */
    bool operator < (const a& other) const {
        return this->get_a() < other.get_a();
    }

    /* needed for set comparison */
    bool operator == (const a& other) const {
        return this->get_a() == other.get_a();
    }
};



class b{
private:
     set<set<a> > b_;
public:
     void set_(set<a> aux){ b_.insert(aux); }

     /* needed, because myset == myset2 is called later in the code */
     bool operator == (const b& other) const {
        return this->b_ == other.b_;
     }

     /* needed, because myset != myset2 is called later in the code */
     bool operator != (const b& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
     }
};
```

You should also take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set and see what other operators `std::set` uses internally on its elements.

Answer (score 0):

No operator (except for the default `operator=(const T&)` and `operator=(T&&)`) is generated by the compiler by default. You should define them explicitly:

```
class b{
private:
     set<set<a> > b_; 
public:
     void set_(set<a> aux){ b_.insert(aux); }
     //Overload operators?

     bool operator==(const b& other) const {
         return b_ == other.b_;
     }

     bool operator!=(const b& other) const {
         return b_ != other.b_;
     } 
};
```

However, this only does not solve the case. Although comparison operators are already defined for `std::set<T>`, they only work if there are operators for `T`. So, in this case, you have to define `operator==` and `operator!=` for your `a` class in the same manner as I showed you with `b` class.